# Read child nodes with same name using StAX

Tags: java, xml-parsing, duplicates, stax, xliff

While trying to read `XML` file using `StAX` I came across this problem.

In an `XML` file (essentially its an `XLIFF` file), I have child nodes with the same name.
I couldn't quite figure out how to read these duplicate nodes.

Below is the part of code that I am trying on, and an example of the `XLIFF` file as well

This is only the working part of the code.

**Java Code:**

```
   // Initialize ArrayList to return
    ArrayList<SourceCollection> xmlData = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean isSource = false;
    boolean isTrans = false;
    boolean isContext = false;
    // Setting Up Data Class
    SourceCollection srcData = null;
   // Start StAX XLIFF reader
    XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(inStream);
        int event = xmlStreamReader.getEventType();
        while (true) {
            switch (event) {
                case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:                            
                    switch (xmlStreamReader.getLocalName()) {
                        case "group":
                            // Create SourceCollection Object
                            srcData = new SourceCollection();
                            srcData.setID(xmlStreamReader.getAttributeValue(0));
                            break;
                        case "source":
                            isSource = true;
                            break;
                        case "target":
                            isTarget = true;
                            break;
                        case "context":
                            isContext = true;
                            break;
                        default:
                            isSource = false;
                            isTarget = false;
                            isContext = false;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS:
                    if (srcData != null) {
                        String srcTrns = xmlStreamReader.getText();
                        if (!Utility.isStringNullOrEmptyOrWhiteSpace(srcTrns)) {
                            if (isSource) {
                                srcData.setSource(srcTrns);
                                isSource = false;
                            } else if (isTarget) {
                                srcData.setTarget(srcTrns);
                                isTarget = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT:
                    if (xmlStreamReader.getLocalName().equals("group")) {
                        xmlData.add(srcData);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            if (!xmlStreamReader.hasNext()) {
                break;
            }
            event = xmlStreamReader.next();
        }
    } catch (XMLStreamException ex) {
        LOG.log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage(), MessageFormat.format("{0} {1}", ex.getCause(), ex.getLocation()));
    }
```

**XLIFF file sample:**

```
<XLIFF>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <file datatype="xml">
    <body>
      <group id="25032014">
        <context-group>
          <context context-type="sub1">xxxx</context>
          <context context-type="sub2">yyyy</context>
          <context context-type="sub3"/>
        </context-group>
        <target-unit>
          <source>ABC</source>
          <target>ABC</target>
        </target-unit>
      </group>
    </body>
  </file>
</xliff>
</XLIFF>
```

Of course, this is a modified XLIFF file, but structure is exactly the same as original.

Any sample or suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you already process these duplicates. I modified your code a little like

```
        switch (event) {
            case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:   
                System.out.println(xmlStreamReader.getLocalName());
                switch (xmlStreamReader.getLocalName()) {
```

and the `System.out` delivers:

```
XLIFF
xliff
file
body
group
context-group
context
context
context
target-unit
source
target
```

You see the multiple `context` outputs. Now you have to adapt your data structure to hold lists of context elements and not only one.

Comment: thanks for the answer, exactly. This loops through nodes. But then how exactly I could hold these elements as list.
Is it like set the Boolean for it and process the node every time it encounters (as I have done for Source and Target)? or there is a way to collect all these at the same time and then process them at once. Sorry, I am still in learning phase of StAX.

Comment: Holding them all at once may not be relevant here, I guess. Since, that is the whole purpose of not using DOM. But still just to know.
I believe I must go through each of them one by one as it encounters.

Comment: Using StAX you are in a way forced to sequential processing. StAX reads simply the elements of XML one by one. So here no aggregation is possible. That is the thing you have to code. If this XML is from a structural point of view a fixed one, you should look into JAXB or a similar framework for pojo mapping. This frameworks deliver you a complete parsed class structure and all the magic of XML parsing, encoding, tags, attributes and so on is completly hidden from you.

Comment: well, that's clear now. thanks for the nice explanation.

Comment: By the way you could nicely combine these techniques to overcome some issues. One Problem from JAXB is memory. The whole XML would be scanned and recreated within your pojo hierarchy (in memory). You could use StaX to stream in the XML and from a specific point on using JAXB to extract sub XMLs into smaller pojos.

Comment: Thanks @wumpz, Yes in fact, I could go with StAX for now, since I know exactly how many duplicate child nodes I have and they can be identified from the attribute values. It's a fixed structure. However, I will go through your suggestions, since I am still in the learning phase of XML parsing and there is a lot to know. Its really nice to use and know benefits of each of these different technologies.